# OSX 10.10 WKWebView set UserAgent (Swift)

Tags: macos, swift, user-agent, wkwebview

i tried to set a Custom UserAgent for the WKWebView in my Mac App. Unfortunately the specified Custom String never gets set. With the iOS SDK it's not a big deal

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent" : "Custom Agent"])
```

But with the Mac SDK it does not work. I also tried

```
   let url = NSURL(string: startURL)
   let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
   req.setValue("Custom Agent/1.0", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

   webView!.loadRequest(req)
```

Thanky you for every help.

Answer (score 4):

You have to expose some private methods of WKWebView in your ObjC bridging header and call them to change the UA.

Adapted snippets from my [mini-browser](https://github.com/kfix/MacPin) app:

### bridging-header.h

```
// https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKWebViewPrivate.h
@import WebKit;
@interface WKWebView (Privates)
@property (copy, setter=_setCustomUserAgent:) NSString *_customUserAgent;
@property (copy, setter=_setApplicationNameForUserAgent:) NSString *_applicationNameForUserAgent;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *_userAgent;
@end
```

### macpin.swift

```
if let agent = withAgent? {
    webview._customUserAgent = agent // specify full UA
} else { 
    webview._applicationNameForUserAgent = "Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5"
    // appended to UA, mimicing Safari
}
webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
```

Comment: This is the only way I have found to make it work. If those of you downvoting this would kindly point to a correct working way, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to upvote because the loss of functionality is there until Apple decides to make these public API in WKWebView. The refinements in WKWebView are wonderful, but it sure would be nice if they were visible outside of the WebKit source code.

Comment: Current WKWebView.h in the webkit.org source shows this, which is a good indication that WWDC 2015 will have something nice ahead soon.

Comment: `/*! @abstract The custom user agent string or nil if no custom user agent string has been set.
*/
@property (WK_NULLABLE_PROPERTY nonatomic, copy) NSString *customUserAgent WK_AVAILABLE(WK_MAC_TBA, WK_IOS_TBA);`

Answer (score 4):

Now, in Swift 2, you can do it without Obj-C with help of new selector API.

Like this:

```
  let webView = WKWebView()
  webView.performSelector("_setApplicationNameForUserAgent:", withObject: "My App User Agent addition")
```

But avoid to use it in production code in this form. Try to hide it somehow :)

Comment: I want to display only mobile-optimized websites within my OSX-App, however, if I try your solution I get the error `[WebView _setApplicationNameForUserAgent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6180001206e0`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mrtn.lxo if you try to do this on OSX, then I recommend you look at official documentation for WebView on OSX. There is usual `applicationNameForUserAgent` property. Therefore you can use it without `performSelector` magic. Also you can set totally custom user agent, that is more appropriate for your aim.